# How do I load Arduino IDE sketches to a RaspberryPi 3+ b?

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi3

I wanted to upload Arduino sketches to my RaspberryPi 3+ b so I downloaded the RasPiArduino folder from me-no-dev and so on but at the end it gave me this error: Error compiling for board RaspberryPi B+/2

How can I make my Pi 3 usable for Arduino?

Comment: That is almost certainly not the entire error message you received.

Comment: fork/exec /home/pi/Downloads/arduino-nightly/hardware/RaspberryPI/piduino/tools/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++: exec format error